AWS RDS - How to get different Users
I have an aws Fargate environment which is accessed by different URL's (project1.tld; project2.tld ...).
There is one database per project in an Aurora DB cluster.
Each database should have a project user and an admin user (the same for all databases).
How can I create these users via the web console?
Thank you very much for your tips!

Unfortunately, it is not possible to manage RDS database users (other than the one admin user) from the AWS web console. You have to connect to your Aurora database using a MySQL or PostgresQL database client, and run the user creation commands there.
